# Slim shows class not found error, even though class exists

Tags: php, slim, autoload

I have a file Sample.php in which I need another file Sample2.php .My directory structure is as follows:

```
\main directory
   \vendor
        \Sample2.php
   \Sample.php
   \myFile.php`
```

The Sample2.php has namespace declaration as `namespace MySample\Practice`.
But when I include the Sample2.php in Sample.php as

```
use MySample\Practice\Sample2.php
```

it gives error **failed to open stream: No such file or directory** .I think it's not able to load the autoload the file.Also the `myFile.php` has the same code but it is working and the code in `Sample.php`,which has some extra things isn't working. What should I do ?

**Sample.php**

```
 use MySample\Practice\Sample2.php;
 $sample2=new Sample2();
 $sample->myFunction();
 //Some other code over here.
```

**Sample2.php**

```
 namespace MySample\Practice;
 class Sample2{
     function_construct(){}
     function myFunction(){}
}
```

The code that is working properly **myFile.php**

```
 use MySample\Practice\Sample2.php;
 $sample2=new Sample2();
 $sample->myFunction();
```

Comment: Without you showing any code, you can only hope you don't get downvoted.

Comment: @NigelRen updated the question.

Comment: Do you have a line which is along the lines of `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` (directory will probably be different) in any of the files?

Comment: no , there is no line like this in any file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added

`require_once __DIR__ . './vendor/autoload.php';`

and it's working fine.